# How do you get nested facets with Searchkick/ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, tire

How can you do nested facets in ElastiSearch with the Searchkick gem?

I would like to achieve something like this:

- Category Name

  - median price
  - count
  - min price
  - max price

Answer (score 0):

`Searchkick` only support term facets, for median price you need stats facets http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html

I suggest you to check elasticsearch-rails or elasticsearch-ruby project.
I used to research all elasticsearch related gem, because of elasticsearch syntax is complex, no gem can provide such flexiable DSL. 
So I like write my own elasticsearch query